# HtmlDownload tag not working when I Push to site, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I am creating an online archive and there is multiple `<a>` tags inside a `<table>` tag.
I am using the `<td>`  with a an overflow in the CSS tags to allow the users to scroll through the list, no php yet.

I do not understand why my download links wont download and comes out with an html file, does anyone know?

```
<tr>
                    <td>Colin syck / alex mei HAUSMUSIC vol2 </td>
                    <td>4.12.14</td>
                    <td>Mp4</td>
                    <th><a href="Arcade/video/2014/ colin syck %3A alex mei HAUSMUSIC vol2 4.12.14.mp4" download>Download</a></th>
                    <th><a href="Arcade/media_player.html" >PLAY</a></th>
                </tr>
```

Comment: do you mean that instead of mp4 download the download is html ?

Comment: Correct!
When I push the html files to my _C-panel_, move the files to the _public_html_, and double check my `<href>` tags.
I still do not see why the browsers download the `<a>` tags

Comment: all the `href` contain spaces ?  maybe it's because of that, try putting  `%20` instead of space in the url link in the `href`

Comment: its the `url encode` of `space` see here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: Do you mean like this ?

`<th><a href="Arcade/video/2014/ colin syck %3A alex mei  HAUSMUSIC vol2 4.12.14.mp4%20" download>Download</a>`

Comment: I think the only reason that does not work is because, these are files on my godaddy web-hosting.

Comment: no like this: `<th><a href="Arcade/video/2014/%20colin%20syck %3A%20alex%20mei  HAUSMUSIC%20vol2%204.12.14.mp4" download>Download</a>`
meaning instead of every space put `%20`

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately still say said failed download.
`<th><a href="%2Fpublic_html%2Fvideo%2F2014%2F%20colin%20syck%20%3A%20alex%20mei%20HAUSMUSIC%20vol2%204.12.14.mp4" download>Download</a></th>`

Maybe because I have my videos in a folder it is confused?

Comment: maybe, but I see that you wore a cupule of times %2 instead of `%20` change it to `%20`

Comment: `<th><a href="/public_html/video/2014/%20colin%20syck%20:%20alex%20mei%20HAUSMUSIC%20vol2%204.12.14.mp4" download>Download</a></th>`


Is this correct?

Comment: think so, is it working ?

Comment: unfortunately  not at the moment.

Comment: maybe its because the url itself try  a referential URL put a `/` before the  `Arcade` folder